# not able to call web api service using http client deploy under virtual application on azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have deploy MVC web application on azure 'app service'. Inside app service I added Web api application by using `virtual application` option available under App Settings on azure. Now I am calling this web api service from MVC web application using HTTP client it throws below error but I am able to call these web api service using browser.

Inner Exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Could you show more details about your webapi code and how do you call the webapi ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think the code you call the webapi may has some error. You could follow my working code as below:

1.Publish MVC web app and add virtual applications.
[image]

2.Publish the Web API to the virtual path.
[image]

3.Use `HttpClient` to call the webapi in `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/joeyAPI/api/");
        //HTTP GET
        var responseTask = client.GetAsync("values");
        responseTask.Wait();
        var result = responseTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            readTask.Wait();
            var students = readTask.Result;
            ViewBag.Message = students.ToString();
         }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Output:

[image]